# jQuery http post without URL

Tags: jquery, http, post

I have a sort of weird problem that has a lot of stupid requirements based on the system I'm using, so please bear with me.

I have two .aspx pages with forms on them (let's call them form1.aspx and form2.aspx) and I need them both to post to the same page, which is also .aspx (let's call this one posted.aspx). Both these forms have a sort of conditional input like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="conditional" value="true" />
```

I need to show different content on posted.aspx based on the value of that input. This content is information about pricing so I cannot use any technique that would encode variables into the URL itself or else someone could cheat their way into the discount pricing.

Really I need a way to either get information passed with HTTP post without knowing whether it came from form1.aspx or form2.aspx and I cannot use PHP.

Comment: Use scripts like VB or C# to control your .aspx pages, then you can do a redirect to posted.aspx with that value e.g. `posted.aspx?conditional=true` and show only data corresponding to this value.

Comment: I'd rather not use that because the content added with jQuery is pricing information and the savvy web user could cheat their way into the discount pricing. I'll add a note about that in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it seems as though `document.referrer` will do exactly what I want.